# Can I create list from regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I'm making a crawler.
User can specify regular expression string to download data.

When user input form is:

```
http://xxx/abc[x-z]/image(9|10|11).png
```

I want to download these.

```
http://xxx/abcx/image9.png
http://xxx/abcy/image9.png
http://xxx/abcz/image9.png
http://xxx/abcx/image10.png
http://xxx/abcy/image10.png
http://xxx/abcz/image10.png
http://xxx/abcx/image11.png
http://xxx/abcy/image11.png
http://xxx/abcz/image11.png
```

Can I create the following list from the above regular expression string? Or, can I use each string in for-in block?

Comment: Add more details, why you want these and what you tried so far..It would help us to find better and quick solution

Comment: you could use loop here

Comment: Your regular expression is invalid, since `[9-11]` is not a valid character class.  We would need more context on what you are actually trying to achieve to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for a lot of advice. I added details. And I try to use `product()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you, I check regular expressions rule :)

Comment: You still have the same issue. `[10-11]` is valid, but it means “one character from this set: `1`, `0`, `1`, `1`”. Not what you want.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I studied and fixed the issue. I found out.

Comment: It should be `[9|10|11]`- if i understand you

Comment: I see. In this case `[9|10|11]` is the best. It's easy to read. And `(9|1[012])` `(9|1[0-3])` are natural, I think. Thank you.

Comment: If you are making a crawler, then regex is fine, do you have a sample of the content that you will be extracting from?

Comment: @miah, No, I don't know what web site and url users have to get for certain. My job is to download web pages matching on regex, in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are wanting to take a user's given regex as an input and generate a list of strings you can use the library [sre_yield](https://github.com/google/sre_yield/):

However, be very aware that trying to parse every possible string of a regex can get out of hand very quickly. You'll need to be sure that your users are aware of the implications that wildcard characters and open ended or repeating groups can have on the number of possible matching strings.

As an example, your regex string: `http://xxx/abc[x-z]/image(9|10|11).png` does not escape the `.`, which is a wildcard for any character, so it will generate a lot of unexpected strings.  Instead we'll need to escape it as seen in the example below:

```
>>> import sre_yield

>>> links = []

>>> for each in sre_yield.AllStrings(r'http://xxx/abc[x-z]/image(9|10|11)\.png'):
        links.append(each)
```

Or more simply `links = list(sre_yield.AllStrings(r'http://xxx/abc[x-z]/image(9|10|11)\.png'))`

The result is:

```
>>> links

['http://xxx/abcx/image9.png', 'http://xxx/abcy/image9.png', 
'http://xxx/abcz/image9.png', 'http://xxx/abcx/image10.png', 
'http://xxx/abcy/image10.png', 'http://xxx/abcz/image10.png', 
'http://xxx/abcx/image11.png', 'http://xxx/abcy/image11.png', 
'http://xxx/abcz/image11.png']
```

Comment: Wow, I tried `sre_yield`. That's perfect. I was able to achieve my purpose. Thank you for your kindness, and I'll take care to `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `product()` from the `itertools` builtin:

```
from itertools import product

for x, y in product(['x', 'y', 'z'], range(9, 12)):
    print 'http://xxx/abc{}/image{}'.format(x, y)
```

To build your list you can use a comprehension:

```
links = ['http://xxx/abc{}/image{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in product(['x', 'y', 'z'], range(9, 12))]
```

Comment: You could, but (a) this doesn't answer the question as written, since it's not creating the list of strings from a regular expression and (b) a nested loop would be much more straight-forward here in my opinion.

Comment: I believe it is useful anyway, because (a) the op does not have a regular expression anyway, from which I guess he is building his own thing, this answer providing a major building block and (b) the cross-product tool is much more versatile, expressive and extensible than nested loops.

Comment: @spectras: I disagree about (b).  `itertools.product()` is heavily overused, and in almost all cases it _reduces_ readability, since it conceals the link between the individual loop variables and the iterables they iterate over and unnecessarily increases verbosity.

Comment: _(Cannot edit my previous comment, but I obviously meant cartesian product, not cross product)_. I disagree though. If you are used to dealing with functional programming, `product` is much more natural than loops. What matters is the output, not the intermediate loop variables.

To me, `product(a, b, c)` is much more readable than a triple loop with intermediate variables and 2 additional levels of nesting. But I guess it's a matter of style.

Comment: @spectras So you are basically saying _all_ nested loops should be written using `itertools.product()`.  I like Haskell, I am used to functional programming, but the context here is Python, so there is no way around the loop variables.  Giving a different out-of-context example doesn't really help the argument that `itertools.product()` should be used _here_ either.

Comment: I would agree that `product()` is not the best approach to every problem.  Especially in situations where the content in the nested loop has a high level of complexity or lots of interaction with the loop variables.  However, in a situation like this, with the goal of simply building a list, `product()` fits perfectly.  It's both minimal and readable, and it's easy enough to check the output to see what it does.  If you'd like to provide an alternate method, then submit a new answer.  In any scenario, this is not the place to argue the use cases of each example.  Start a new question for that.

Comment: @Jkdc: I would provide an answer only once I know what the question actually is.  So far, that's not really clear.

Comment: Thank you for your usefull code. Hmm, when using `product()`, I have to analysis regular expression string that user inputted and create ['x', 'y', 'z'] list, isn'it? Hmm, It seems difficult for me than I thought.

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa Instead of editing I've submitted another answer which may more closely fit your request.  I'll leave this one here since it does not require an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Simple try may be-alternative to the previous answers

```
lst = ['http://xxx/abc%s/image%s.png'%(x,y) for x, y in [(j,i) for i in (9,10,11) for j in ('x', 'y', 'z')]]
```

Omitted `range` and `format` function for quicker performance.

---

Analysis- I compared my way and the way posted by `Jkdc`

I ran both way **100000 times** but mean shows that **itertools** approach is faster in terms of execution time-

```
from itertools import product
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

prodct = []
native = []

def test():
    start = time.clock()
    lst = ['http://xxx/abc{}/image{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in product(('x', 'y', 'z'), range(9, 11))]
    end = time.clock()

    print '{0:.50f}'.format(end-start)
    prodct.append('{0:.50f}'.format(end-start))

    start1 = time.clock()
    lst = ['http://xxx/abc%s/image%s'%(x,y) for x, y in [(j,i) for i in (9,10,11) for j in ('x', 'y', 'z')]]
    end1 = time.clock()

    print '{0:.50f}'.format(end1-start1)
    native.append('{0:.50f}'.format(end1-start1))


for i in range(1,100000):
    test()


y = np.dot(np.array(native).astype(np.float),100000)
x= np.dot(np.array(prodct).astype(np.float),100000)

print np.mean(y)
print np.mean(x)
```

[image: graph]
and getting result for `native`(no module) and `itertools-product` as below

for native `2.1831179834`
for itertools-product `1.60410432562`